# Sending out attached PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, outlook

I am trying to attach a created pdf file to my email in Outlook. Everything is working except the attachment part.

Find below my code:

```vb
Sub sendApplicationMail()
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
    ChDir strPath
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & "CreatedFile.pdf"
    
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    Dim myAttachments As Object
    
    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set myAttachments = OutLookMailItem.Attachments
    
    With OutLookMailItem
        .To = "max.mustermannm@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "My Data"
        .Body = "Dear team" & "," & vbCrLf & "please find attached my pdf."
        .myAttachments.Add strPath & "CreatedFile.pdf"
        '.send 
        .Display
    End With
    
    Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
    Set OutLookApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does that line throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
.Attachments.Add strPath & "CreatedFile.pdf"
```

There's no need for myAttachments here

Tested and working:

```vb
Sub sendApplicationMail()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    
    strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & "CreatedFile.pdf"
    
    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    
    With OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
        .To = "max.mustermannm@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "My Data"
        .Body = "Dear team" & "," & vbCrLf & "please find attached my pdf."
        .Attachments.Add strPath & "CreatedFile.pdf"
        '.send
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim,  the following line is troubleshooting: myAttachments.Add strPath & "CreatedFile.pdf". 

I just want to attach my created pdf to the email. 

What’s the difference between myAttachments and .Attachments.Add?
Best regards!

Comment: `myAttachments` is not a property of `OutLookMailItem`, so your posted line doesn't work.  Did you try what I posted above?

Comment: A bug. With that change, the locals window shows `myAttachments.Count` change from 0 to 1.

Comment: Is the attachment added to the mail though?  And what do you mean by "a bug" ?

Comment: The attachment is not added with `myAttachments.Add` but with `Set myAttachments = OutLookMailItem.Attachments` the `myAttachments` object exists.  The `myAttachments.Count` property updates with`.Attachments.Add`. Still `Debug.Print myAttachments.Count` remains invalid while visible in the Locals window.

Comment: Forget `myAttachments` - you don't need it and it's just getting in the way of fixing your issue, which seems to be that you're not able to add the attachment to the mail.

Comment: Hi Tim, sry for the delay, but I have tested your solution and its working perfectly! Thanks for your help and I wish you guys a happy 2021!